# ERROR Error- Uncaught (in promise) - Error - Token must be defined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am adding a canDeactivate guard to one of my routes. I create the service, add it to providers of the Feature module, add it on the route itself. When I try to access the route, I get an exception shown below.

The canDeactivate for now is very simple:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanDeactivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { IrEditComponent } from'./index';


@Injectable()
export class ReferralGuardService implements CanDeactivate<IrEditComponent> {

  canDeactivate(component: IrEditComponent) { 
    return true;
  }
}
```

The exception is as follows:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!
>   Error: Token must be defined! at new ReflectiveKey (core.es5.js:1405)
>   [angular] at
>   KeyRegistry.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.KeyRegistry.get
>   (core.es5.js:1452) [angular] at 
>   Function.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveKey.get
>   (core.es5.js:1423) [angular]
>       at     ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get
>   (core.es5.js:2489) [angular]
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9473) [angular]
>       at 
>       NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.es5.js:10555) [angular]
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9473) [angular]
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.es5.js:10555) [angular]
>       at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.getToken
>   (router.es5.js:4566) [angular]
>       at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.getResolver
>   (router.es5.js:4554) [angular]
>       at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.resolveNode
>   (router.es5.js:4534) [angular]
>       at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.runResolve
>   (router.es5.js:4515) [angular]
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.es5.js:4282) [angular]
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
>   (mergeMap.js:120) [angular]
>       at new ReflectiveKey (core.es5.js:1405) [angular]